# Java Problems when Running Ant: noclassdef

Tags: java, ant, command-line

Windows 7, Java jdk1.6.0_32, Ant 1.9

User & System variables:

**JAVA_HOME**:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32

**PATH**:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32;c:\ant\bin;

```
ANT_HOME:c:\ANT

Run command prompt as administrator
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

H:\>c:

C:\>w:

W:\>cd webadvisor

W:\WebAdvisor>cd wasql*

W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3>c:\ant\bin\ant
Buildfile: W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\build.xml

init:

prepare:
 [echo] Preparing Update...
 [copy] Copying 208 files to W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\temp
 [copy] Copying 129 files to W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\temp
 [copy] Copying 49 files to W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\temp

splitdocs:

merge-cleanup:
[delete] Deleting: W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\custom\WEB-INF\web.xml

findwebxml:

merge:

datatelxmloverride:

mergeDefault:

BUILD FAILED
W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\build.xml:112: The following error occurred while executing this line:
W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\build.xml:165: The following error occurred while executing this line:
W:\WebAdvisor\WASQLTEST3\build.xml:173: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat
        at org.codehaus.cargo.module.webapp.WebXmlIo.writeWebXml(WebXmlIo.java:256)
        at org.codehaus.cargo.module.webapp.WebXmlIo.writeWebXml(WebXmlIo.java:225)
        at org.apache.cactus.integration.ant.WebXmlMergeTask.execute(WebXmlMergeTask.java:120)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class path is missing  the required jar for

```
org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat
```

Check if you have `xercesImpl.jar` in your classpath

**EDIT** :

This you can set by including  the required jars in ant compile target and put all the required jars in the lib folder.

```
<target name="compile" depends=""   description="compile the java source files">  
 <javac srcdir="." destdir="${build}">  
    <classpath>  
        <fileset dir="${lib}">  
            <include name="**/*.jar" />  
        </fileset>  
    </classpath>  
</javac>
```

Comment: i found a file called xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar and put it in c:\ CLASSPATH=.;C:\xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar; What else do I need to do?

Comment: Include then in ant compile classpath. Edited the answer

Comment: included in antlib folder and it worked like magic.  thank you @nullpointerexception

Answer (score 1):

org/apache/xml/serialize/OutputFormat is a Xerces class... search your system for xerces*.jar.  Does this file exist?  Is it in your classpath?

Comment: i found a file called xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar and put it in c:\


CLASSPATH=.;C:\xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar;

What else do I need to do?